# What does 大洞套小洞，洞洞相通 mean

Tags: translation, meaning

can anyone please tell me this sentence’s translation from Chinese to English 我说欢迎你们下次再来，那个时候十八洞开发出来了，大洞套小洞，洞洞相通，保证你们比这次玩得还开心！
What does 大洞套小洞，洞洞相通 mean here exactly

Answer (score 1):

I guess the 十八洞 refers to a Chinese scenic area. If it does, the "大洞套小洞， 洞洞相通" means: You can find small cave inside a big cave, and every cave here can connected each other directly or indirectly. This is the literal meaning. This sentence actually want to say, when the scenic area is fully developed, caves here will be particularly fun.